# How to Determine the Return Type of a Generic Function? Function Return Types are different objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `fn`, I want this function to return the appropriate object type based on the `typename` parameter, but I don't have access to the types `A` and `B`.

For example, if the function is called `fn({} as C, "B")` then the function must return type `B`, as well as `A`.

I could pass `return {} as A` but again I don't have access to `A` and `B`, the function must be able to infer them via the `C` type and `typename` parameters.

Is this possible?

```js
type A = { typename: "A" };
type B = { typename: "B"; message: string };

type C = A | B;

const fn = <TData extends C, TTypeName extends C["typename"]>(
  data: TData,
  typename: TTypeName
) => {
  // I can't do this, because I can't access "A" and "B", it has to be inferred via "C".
  // return data as B; 
};
```

Comment: Why is `fn` specific to `C` if it's generic? (What could `TData` be other than `C`?  Could it really be just `A` or something?  Why bother if `TTypeName` will narrow it?)  I'd expect `fn` to allow anything with a `typename` as `TData` and then constrain `TTypeName` to `TData["typename"]` instead.  Otherwise this seems uselessly generic.   If my suggestion is okay, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9YGVN) is how I'd do it, and I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, please [edit] to make your [mre] motivate making `TData` generic, and/or clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks, your approach works as expected. I did this actually to extract the error message returned by ApolloClient, the error object returned as usual is not wrapped in ApolloClientError/GrpahQLError. The objects returned are `{__typename: "CreatePostError", fields?: Record<string,string>}` for errors and `{__typename: "Post", title: string}` on success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type to filter a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to get just those members which match another type.  In your case `TData` is expected to be a union, and `TTypeName` is the `typename` property of the member you'd like to extract.  So your return type should be `Extract<TData, { typename: TTypeName }>`:

```
const fn = <
  TData extends { typename: string },
  TTypeName extends TData["typename"]
>(
  data: TData,
  typename: TTypeName
) => {
  return data as Extract<TData, { typename: TTypeName }>    
};
```

Note that I changed the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `TData` to be `{ typename: string }` instead of `C`.  Presumably this code should work on *any* `data` that has a string-valued `typename` property, not just one that matches `C` exactly.

Anyway, let's test it out:

```
type A = { typename: "A" };
type B = { typename: "B"; message: string };    
type C = A | B;

const b = fn({} as C, "B");
// const b: B

const a = fn({} as C, "A");
// const a: A
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIBml4F54B5j3gFQCICGsh8ApgB6xmQAm08A3vLAJ4AONhAtmQFzw4AJwCWkAObwAvgBpseXBzIA5HmXJUa9PERIBtAERtOkNQYC6wAHwAKebWKEBBR3JzGuvZ4s6rewAEo0KyZ5ITJYAFchFAcSeEIGAFEqIUJQWAwXEhkmFiVTLwUlP3UpKxApAG4QD3gAQTQ8j0L+eAN6g2kauoAhJuYWtQEDXoMq+F5oaEJxNuExSWrapXgAYSbGgB94XpqIGAQAIybkG0YpBIY13NGDAJqAekf4A7h4I4FekDeEUnQzhcrutbp0HsBnq8oO8nA0gA)